# How to read XML items or data in a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

It looks like we are trying to parse XML and certain values? Do we do that always with T.item.value? and T(Item) an alias here? I found reference here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/load-xml-data?view=sql-server-2017 but still need clarification.

Need to understand what this code is doing and where can I learn more about writing such code like what is T, T(item), T.item.value here..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTestSP] 
  @exServers xml = N'<a />' --sample: N'<a><s>abc.com</s><s u="user@example.com>outlook.com</s></a>'  
AS  
BEGIN  
    select   
        T.item.value('.', 'nvarchar(256)') as ExServer,  
        T.item.value('@u', 'nvarchar(256)') as Account  
        from @exServers.nodes('a/s') T(item) 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by going through the tutorial [Stairway to XML](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/92778/). After that all will be clear to you.

---

> what is T?

`T` is an alias for a table of shredded xml fragments from `@exServers`.

> what is T(item)?

This specifies the name `T` of the derived table from shredding the nodes and it is giving the column with the XML fragments a name `item`.

> T.item.value

It is a way to extract a value from the xml in column `item` from the alias `T`.

---

[nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)
[value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)